# Parse set User email verification to true manually

Tags: email, parse-platform, verification

So it appears when you create a User in Parse you cannot manually set their activation as True, rather you have to authenticate the account by email.

This is a problem if you are switching an existing database to Parse since you wouldn't want every user to recreate their account. Is there a way to force the emailVerified to True?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option on your parse dashboard to enable/disable this feature on the users end http://blog.parse.com/2012/04/03/introducing-app-email-settings/. Otherwise it defeats the purpose and intent of security for users if you manually override it. It would be cool for someone else to use my email they retrieved from a phishing scam latter to find out it was approved by devs of an app I haven't even used.

---

**EDIT** Per our discussion below;

As an admin, you can not set any objects emailVerified set to true or false for security reasons, and before you dig deep into Parse, a user can't alter another users information either. Some alternatives you can consider:

> Users which were created before email verification was on or which were created without an email will not have the emailVerified key

- So in other words, you can import a CSV/JSON file of your old database and leave the emailVerified undefined, which won't prompt anything on the users end, except when they request a password reset or other circumstantial events. However, you can always check if an emailVerified field is set to true for any object at any time and act accordingly.
- You can post an updated privacy policy and have them update their information and reverify at that time, even though you specifically stated you don't want to go this avenue. But as databases change, so should privacy policies.
- The only time, **when using Parse that is**, the boolean value of emailVerified will change is once the user clicks on the link sent to their email. A last resort would be send a mass email to all users, this isn't as far fetched an option, many companies have users reverify emails.

Comment: I think you might misunderstand, I don't want to use an unverified email rather I want to port user accounts from an existing verified user database into Parse without having to ask the users to reverify all over again

Comment: There is no way around that @Parad0x13 even as an admin. You can import a CSV file of your old database and leave the emailVerified undefined, which won't prompt anything on the users end, except when they request a password reset. You can always check if an emailVerified is set to true for any object at any time and act accordingly, otherwise you can just post a new privacy policy and have them update their information and reverify at that time. "Users which were created before email verification was on or which were created without an email will not have the emailVerified key."

Comment: Understood, thank you. Your first post made it seem as though you thought I was trying to arbitrarily use email addresses without verification. I get that parse is supporting user security but I don't think it's their place to force me to manage my database in any one particular way. However thank you for your clarification and now I can move forward

Comment: No your right @Parad0x13 i misunderstood your intent. I'll edit for future question seekers. Parse is great I love it, but just like everything else good in the world, short-comings are evident. I have a few personal pet peeves with the dashboard myself. You can always submit your feedback to them in their dev google group.